# iphone - Sharpen UIImage

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, uiimage

I want to sharpen images in my app.

I found this post

[how to sharp/blur an uiimage in iphone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1486051/how-to-sharp-blur-an-uiimage-in-iphone)

and also had a look at Apple's sample

[GLImageProcessing](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/GLImageProcessing/index.html)

But that OpenGL ES thing killed my brain cells a lot and I still don't get it.

So, Can anyone pls give me a piece of helper code to sharpen an UIImage?

Thanks

Comment: +1 For But that OpenGL ES thing killed my brain cells a lot and I still don't get it, that is ammusing.. :)

Comment: So which lib did you end up using? I'm losing brain cells myself!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This library might be just what you need - it has an image sharpen method. Just came across it myself, haven't tried it yet. Let me know if it works ;)

https://github.com/esilverberg/ios-image-filters

Comment: it is working, but too slow. 6 secs for an image with 600 * 400