# GLImageProcessing ROI (Region of Interest)

Tags: ios, image-processing, opengl-es, ios5, roi

I am currently trying to blur a part of an image.  I use apple's example code [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GLImageProcessing/Introduction/Intro.html)

The example code itself can blur whole image and draw it to the EAGLView, what I want to do is blur only part of the image by supplying an ROI.

I do not know how to supply an ROI to the function.

Here is the code which draws image to the view;

```
void drawGL(int wide, int high, float val, int mode)
{
static int prevmode = -1;
typedef void (*procfunc)(V2fT2f *, float);

typedef struct {
    procfunc func;
    procfunc degen;
} Filter;

const Filter filter[] = {
    { brightness             },
    { contrast               },
    { extrapolate, greyscale },
    { hue                    },
    { extrapolate, blur      }, // The blur could be exaggerated by downsampling to half size
};
#define NUM_FILTERS (sizeof(filter)/sizeof(filter[0]))
rt_assert(mode < NUM_FILTERS);

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrthof(0, wide, 0, high, -1, 1);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
glScalef(wide, high, 1);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, Input.texID);

if (prevmode != mode)
{
    prevmode = mode;
    if (filter[mode].degen)
    {
        // Cache degenerate image, potentially a different size than the system framebuffer
        glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, DegenFBO);
        glViewport(0, 0, Degen.wide*Degen.s, Degen.high*Degen.t);
        // The entire framebuffer won't be written to if the image was padded to POT.
        // In this case, clearing is a performance win on TBDR systems.
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glDisable(GL_BLEND);
        filter[mode].degen(fullquad, 1.0);
        glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, SystemFBO);
    }
}

// Render filtered image to system framebuffer
glViewport(0, 0, wide, high);
filter[mode].func(flipquad, val);
glCheckError();
}
```

And this is the function which blurs the image;

```
static void blur(V2fT2f *quad, float t) // t = 1
{
GLint tex;
V2fT2f tmpquad[4];
float offw = t / Input.wide;
float offh = t / Input.high;
int i;

glGetIntegerv(GL_TEXTURE_BINDING_2D, &tex);

// Three pass small blur, using rotated pattern to sample 17 texels:
//
// .\/.. 
// ./\\/ 
// \/X/\   rotated samples filter across texel corners
// /\\/. 
// ../\. 

// Pass one: center nearest sample
glVertexPointer  (2, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(V2fT2f), &quad[0].x);
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(V2fT2f), &quad[0].s);
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);
glColor4f(1.0/5, 1.0/5, 1.0/5, 1.0);
validateTexEnv();
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

// Pass two: accumulate two rotated linear samples
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE);
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    tmpquad[i].x = quad[i].s + 1.5 * offw;
    tmpquad[i].y = quad[i].t + 0.5 * offh;
    tmpquad[i].s = quad[i].s - 1.5 * offw;
    tmpquad[i].t = quad[i].t - 0.5 * offh;
}
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(V2fT2f), &tmpquad[0].x);
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_REPLACE);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glClientActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(V2fT2f), &tmpquad[0].s);
glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_COMBINE);
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_COMBINE_RGB,      GL_INTERPOLATE);
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_SRC0_RGB,         GL_TEXTURE);
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_SRC1_RGB,         GL_PREVIOUS);
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_SRC2_RGB,         GL_PRIMARY_COLOR);
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_OPERAND2_RGB,     GL_SRC_COLOR);
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_COMBINE_ALPHA,    GL_REPLACE);
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_SRC0_ALPHA,       GL_PRIMARY_COLOR);

glColor4f(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 2.0/5);
validateTexEnv();
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

// Pass three: accumulate two rotated linear samples
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    tmpquad[i].x = quad[i].s - 0.5 * offw;
    tmpquad[i].y = quad[i].t + 1.5 * offh;
    tmpquad[i].s = quad[i].s + 0.5 * offw;
    tmpquad[i].t = quad[i].t - 1.5 * offh;
}
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

// Restore state
glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
glClientActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, Half.texID);
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_OPERAND2_RGB,     GL_SRC_ALPHA);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glDisable(GL_BLEND);
}
```

Where should I supply an ROI or if any other way is possible to blur a part of an image without ROI, I would like to know as well.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Im not a big OpenGL ES knower, but this code operate with whole (not ROI) textures on surface. 
I using this example too.

I think, you should:

- cut ROI of your image
- create new texture with this image
- blur whole new texture
- set new texture over your original texture

Also few links:
[How to implement a box or gaussian blur on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140117/how-to-implement-a-box-or-gaussian-blur-on-iphone), [Blur Effect (Wet in Wet effect) in Paint Application Using OpenGL-ES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6980402/blur-effect-wet-in-wet-effect-in-paint-application-using-opengl-es),
[how to sharp/blur an uiimage in iphone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1486051/how-to-sharp-blur-an-uiimage-in-iphone)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried glScissor() yet?

from the GLES1.1 spec:

> glScissor defines a rectangle, called the scissor box, in window
>   coordinates. The first two arguments, x and y, specify the lower left
>   corner of the box. width and height specify the width and height of
>   the box.
>
> To enable and disable the scissor test, call glEnable and glDisable
>   with argument GL_SCISSOR_TEST. The scissor test is initially disabled.
>   While scissor test is enabled, only pixels that lie within the scissor
>   box can be modified by drawing commands. Window coordinates have
>   integer values at the shared corners of frame buffer pixels.
>   glScissor(0, 0, 1, 1) allows modification of only the lower left pixel
>   in the window,and glScissor(0, 0, 0, 0) doesn't allow modification of
>   any pixels in the window.

You might have to do 2 draw passes; first the unfiltered image; the second is the filtered image but drawn with the scissor test.

Comment: Is it possible to create a circular area with glScissor() ?

Comment: No, the spec explicitly states it is a rectangle. If you want circles, you'll have to use alpha masks.