# How to add Gausian blur to a UIImage with Transparency

Tags: uiimage, core-graphics, blur

I read this answer: [how to sharp/blur an uiimage in iphone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1486051/how-to-sharp-blur-an-uiimage-in-iphone)

As well as dozens and dozens of other answers and tutorials on shadows and blur.
It does not work, including all of the source links in the answers.

What I get any time I attempt to blur an image from a png file which has transparent areas. Is an image that is (when not using the source pasted in the above answers) a blurry image where all of the transparent areas are filled with noise.

After trying every piece of sample code I've found for the past 5 days with no luck what soever I have around 50 hours in to this and have accomplished less than I had before I started. So I am wondering, how can you add gaussianblur to a UIImage that has transparent pixels?

Better yet… I am attempting to take a UIImage, sometimes created from a UILabel, and add a shadow to it that can be tilted to appear like it falls on the ground behind and beneath the image like a shadow cast by the sun on the ground. It was suggested that I should take the image, convert it to grayscale and blur it out then apply the transform… Great idea, except that, as stated above, because all of these images have a great deal of transparent pixels I end up with a stark square of almost nothing but noise.

I should note, core graphics are a really weak point for me, so I could look at the example code all day and never understand it enough to tweak it to work.

Comment: Does no one know or does my question not make sense?